# How to manage multiple email addresses on multiple domains in Exchange

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2010

Using Hosted Exchange Server, mostly because I use an iPhone, webmail & Outlook on 2 laptops. I want to keep everything consistent and unfragmented. Also, I want push notifications.

1. I have 2 domains, a professional one & a personal one.
2. Each domain has about 5 (give or take) email addresses I use for various purposes.
3. Each domain also has a few parked domains (.net, .org, .info) aliased to the .com domain.

I would like to keep emails from the 2 domains separated. Do I need an extra mail box, meaning extra expense or can I create another Exchange user on the same mailbox and create an extra account in Outlook? In either case I will have to wait for iOS4 on the iPhone to manage 2 Exchange accounts. Or am I better off just using a set of rules and folders?

The aliased domains are another joy to behold entirely. It looks like I will have to add each email address variant individually. Alternatively, I reckon I may just leave the aliased domains at the pop3 host and let Outlook gather those as edge-cases.

Surely I can't be the only one making my life this difficult. Anyone out there done this?

From the left field - is this (much) easier in gMail? I'm not committed to Exchange (yet).

[edit] or should I just use IMAP with my original host? [/edit]

Previously I used Outlook as a pop3 client with a set of filters to direct incoming traffic to folders. This worked with the aliased domains because my host directed all the aliased TLDs to the same mailbox.

Comment: Years later... Google apps. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:** Outlook.com (formerly Hotmail) offers free e-mail hosting on your own domain name at http://domains.live.com/, with up to 50 accounts. It supports push e-mail on the iPhone and [is supported in Outlook 2013](http://blogs.office.com/2012/11/15/put-the-power-of-outlook-2013-behind-your-outlook-com-email/).

This is worth exploring for those who weren’t lucky enough to be grandfathered in to the free version of Google Apps.

---

**UPDATE:** As of December, 2012, [you can no longer sign up for free Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=en). Paid accounts are available for $50 per user per year, and they continue to support ActiveSync as well as the Outlook plug-in.

---

I can't speak to hosted Exchange, but given that Gmail (actually [Google Apps for Your Domain](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html)) is free for up to 50 users, you could easily set up two domains. They support ActiveSync, so once iOS 4 comes out you should be home free, setting it up as two "Exchange" accounts. You can add domain aliases, so `you@yourcompany.com` and `you@yourcompany.net` would both go to the same mailbox.

Note, however, that it only supports the ActiveSync protocol, not the full Exchange Web Services protocol used by Outoook. Google does provide a [plug-in for Outlook](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/outlook_sync.html) that gives full functionality, but it requires the Premier Edition ($50 per year, per user).

With the free Standard Edition you'll need to use IMAP to inter-operate with Outlook, and I'm not sure how it will deal with calendars and contacts. Of course you could use their web-based interfaces, which are quite good.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. It works like a charm and was a piece of cake to set up.